# How are documents in CollectionFS able to store methods in MongoDB?

Tags: meteor, collectionfs

I'm using the Amazon S3 storage adapter with CollectionFS.

Normally you can't store a method into MongoDB. For example, I can't have a document stored in my `CustomerOrders` collection with a method on it that modifies the document directly with a discount code.

`CustomerOrders.findOne().addDiscountCode('SAVE50PERCENT')`

But with CollectionFS and the S3 storage adapter I'm able to run a `remove` function to delete an item from my Images collection as well as delete it from my Amazon S3 bucket:

```
Images.findOne().remove(function(error, success){
  console.log(success)
});
```

The similarity in syntax struck me. It's basically saying:

- Go into the Images collection
- find a random document
- return it as an object
- run the `.remove()` method that's on that object

However, actually declaring the collection is different.

Instead of doing the following to create my `Images` collection,

`Images = new Mongo.Collection('images');`

I have to do:

```
Images = new FS.Collection("images", {
  stores: [storeName],
  filter: {
    allow: {
      contentTypes: ['image/*']
    }
  }
})
```

I'm guessing that `FS.Collection` extended `Mongo.Collection's` `findOne()` method so the code can:

- Go into the Images collection
- find a random document
- return it as an object
- add a `.remove()` method onto this object
- return this extended object
- run the `.remove()` method that's on that object

Is this kind of correct? The `.remove` method isn't actually stored in the document itself. It's simply added onto the document object that's returned in `findOne()`?

Answer (score 0):

The remove method comes from a prototype in the FS Collection package (which extends the typical collection capabilities and modifies default behavior), so you are correct.
If you take a look at the cfs:collection package, and the api.common.js, you can see exactly how these methods are defined:
[api.common.js](https://github.com/CollectionFS/DEPRECATING-cfs-collection/blob/master/packages/collection/api.common.js)